# having issues setting this code to pull up with input variables

Tags: java, html, html5-canvas

soo bit of a problem here.  I'm trying to take the java and make the room_count come from a value from the HTML page. and same with the Room Size also. the orional code (the last set of code) works great if you change the values inside of the code...however when i try to click the button with the current (first set of code) it lags and i have to kill the internet tab using it.... any help would be nice

```
  <piece> <!-- Body of the page -->
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
        <p>Room Count</p>
        <label for="MinRoomCount">Minimum</label>
        <input type="number" id="MinRoomCount" name="MinRoomCount" value="1"></input>
        <label for="MaxRoomCount">Maximum</label>
        <input type="number" id="MaxRoomCount" name="MaxRoomCount" value="10"></input>
        <p>Room Size</p>
        <label for="MinRoomSize">Minimum</label>
        <input type="number" id="MinRoomSize" name="MinRoomSize" value="5"></input>
        <label for="MaxRoomSize">Maximum</label>
        <input type="number" id="MaxRoomSize" name="MaxRoomSize" value="15"></input>            
    <input type="button" onclick="regenerate()"></input>
    <script>
        function regenerate(){
        var Dungeon = {
            map: null,
            map_size: 200,
            rooms: [],
            Generate: function () {
                var MaxA = document.getElementById("MaxRoomCount").value;
                var MinA = document.getElementById("MinRoomCount").value;
                var MaxB = document.getElementById("MaxRoomSize").value;
                var MinB = document.getElementById("MinRoomSize").value;
                this.map = [];
                for (var x = 0; x < this.map_size; x++) {
                    this.map[x] = [];
                    for (var y = 0; y < this.map_size; y++) {
                        this.map[x][y] = 0;
                    }
                }

                var room_count = Helpers.GetRandom(MinA, MaxA);
                var min_size = MinB;
                var max_size = MaxB;

                for (var i = 0; i < room_count; i++) {
                    var room = {};

                    room.x = Helpers.GetRandom(1, this.map_size - max_size - 1);
                    room.y = Helpers.GetRandom(1, this.map_size - max_size - 1);
                    room.w = Helpers.GetRandom(min_size, max_size);
                    room.h = Helpers.GetRandom(min_size, max_size);

                    if (this.DoesCollide(room)) {
                        i--;
                        continue;
                    }
                    room.w--;
                    room.h--;

                    this.rooms.push(room);
                }

                this.SquashRooms();

                for (i = 0; i < room_count; i++) {
                    var roomA = this.rooms[i];
                    var roomB = this.FindClosestRoom(roomA);

                    pointA = {
                        x: Helpers.GetRandom(roomA.x, roomA.x + roomA.w),
                        y: Helpers.GetRandom(roomA.y, roomA.y + roomA.h)
                    };
                    pointB = {
                        x: Helpers.GetRandom(roomB.x, roomB.x + roomB.w),
                        y: Helpers.GetRandom(roomB.y, roomB.y + roomB.h)
                    };

                    while ((pointB.x != pointA.x) || (pointB.y != pointA.y)) {
                        if (pointB.x != pointA.x) {
                            if (pointB.x > pointA.x) pointB.x--;
                            else pointB.x++;
                        } else if (pointB.y != pointA.y) {
                            if (pointB.y > pointA.y) pointB.y--;
                            else pointB.y++;
                        }

                        this.map[pointB.x][pointB.y] = 1;
                    }
                }

                for (i = 0; i < room_count; i++) {
                    var room = this.rooms[i];
                    for (var x = room.x; x < room.x + room.w; x++) {
                        for (var y = room.y; y < room.y + room.h; y++) {
                            this.map[x][y] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (var x = 0; x < this.map_size; x++) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < this.map_size; y++) {
                        if (this.map[x][y] == 1) {
                            for (var xx = x - 1; xx <= x + 1; xx++) {
                                for (var yy = y - 1; yy <= y + 1; yy++) {
                                    if (this.map[xx][yy] == 0) this.map[xx][yy] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            FindClosestRoom: function (room) {
                var mid = {
                    x: room.x + (room.w / 2),
                    y: room.y + (room.h / 2)
                };
                var closest = null;
                var closest_distance = 1000;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.rooms.length; i++) {
                    var check = this.rooms[i];
                    if (check == room) continue;
                    var check_mid = {
                        x: check.x + (check.w / 2),
                        y: check.y + (check.h / 2)
                    };
                    var distance = Math.min(Math.abs(mid.x - check_mid.x) - (room.w / 2) - (check.w / 2), Math.abs(mid.y - check_mid.y) - (room.h / 2) - (check.h / 2));
                    if (distance < closest_distance) {
                        closest_distance = distance;
                        closest = check;
                    }
                }
                return closest;
            },
            SquashRooms: function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < this.rooms.length; j++) {
                        var room = this.rooms[j];
                        while (true) {
                            var old_position = {
                                x: room.x,
                                y: room.y
                            };
                            if (room.x > 1) room.x--;
                            if (room.y > 1) room.y--;
                            if ((room.x == 1) && (room.y == 1)) break;
                            if (this.DoesCollide(room, j)) {
                                room.x = old_position.x;
                                room.y = old_position.y;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            DoesCollide: function (room, ignore) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.rooms.length; i++) {
                    if (i == ignore) continue;
                    var check = this.rooms[i];
                    if (!((room.x + room.w < check.x) || (room.x > check.x + check.w) || (room.y + room.h < check.y) || (room.y > check.y + check.h))) return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        var Renderer = {
            canvas: null,
            ctx: null,
            size: 512,
            scale: 0,
            Initialize: function () {
                this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                this.canvas.width = this.size;
                this.canvas.height = this.size;
                this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                this.scale = this.canvas.width / Dungeon.map_size;
            },
            Update: function () {
                for (var y = 0; y < Dungeon.map_size; y++) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < Dungeon.map_size; x++) {
                        var tile = Dungeon.map[x][y];
                        if (tile == 0) this.ctx.fillStyle = '#351330';
                        else if (tile == 1) this.ctx.fillStyle = '#64908A';
                        else this.ctx.fillStyle = '#424254';
                        this.ctx.fillRect(x * this.scale, y * this.scale, this.scale, this.scale);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var Helpers = {
            GetRandom: function (low, high) {
                return~~ (Math.random() * (high - low)) + low;
            }
        };

        Dungeon.Generate();
        Renderer.Initialize();
        Renderer.Update(Dungeon.map);
        }
    </script>
```

Here's the Origional

```
   <piece> <!-- Body of the page -->
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
        <p>Room Count</p>
        <label for="MinRoomCount">Minimum</label>
        <input type="number" id="MinRoomCount" name="MinRoomCount" value="1"></input>
        <label for="MaxRoomCount">Maximum</label>
        <input type="number" id="MaxRoomCount" name="MaxRoomCount" value="10"></input>
        <p>Room Size</p>
        <label for="MinRoomSize">Minimum</label>
        <input type="number" id="MinRoomSize" name="MinRoomSize" value="5"></input>
        <label for="MaxRoomSize">Maximum</label>
        <input type="number" id="MaxRoomSize" name="MaxRoomSize" value="15"></input>            
    <input type="button" onclick="regenerate()"></input>
    <script>
        function regenerate(){
        var Dungeon = {
            map: null,
            map_size: 200,
            rooms: [],
            Generate: function () {
                this.map = [];
                for (var x = 0; x < this.map_size; x++) {
                    this.map[x] = [];
                    for (var y = 0; y < this.map_size; y++) {
                        this.map[x][y] = 0;
                    }
                }

                var room_count = Helpers.GetRandom(1, 100);
                var min_size = 5;
                var max_size = 15;

                for (var i = 0; i < room_count; i++) {
                    var room = {};

                    room.x = Helpers.GetRandom(1, this.map_size - max_size - 1);
                    room.y = Helpers.GetRandom(1, this.map_size - max_size - 1);
                    room.w = Helpers.GetRandom(min_size, max_size);
                    room.h = Helpers.GetRandom(min_size, max_size);

                    if (this.DoesCollide(room)) {
                        i--;
                        continue;
                    }
                    room.w--;
                    room.h--;

                    this.rooms.push(room);
                }

                this.SquashRooms();

                for (i = 0; i < room_count; i++) {
                    var roomA = this.rooms[i];
                    var roomB = this.FindClosestRoom(roomA);

                    pointA = {
                        x: Helpers.GetRandom(roomA.x, roomA.x + roomA.w),
                        y: Helpers.GetRandom(roomA.y, roomA.y + roomA.h)
                    };
                    pointB = {
                        x: Helpers.GetRandom(roomB.x, roomB.x + roomB.w),
                        y: Helpers.GetRandom(roomB.y, roomB.y + roomB.h)
                    };

                    while ((pointB.x != pointA.x) || (pointB.y != pointA.y)) {
                        if (pointB.x != pointA.x) {
                            if (pointB.x > pointA.x) pointB.x--;
                            else pointB.x++;
                        } else if (pointB.y != pointA.y) {
                            if (pointB.y > pointA.y) pointB.y--;
                            else pointB.y++;
                        }

                        this.map[pointB.x][pointB.y] = 1;
                    }
                }

                for (i = 0; i < room_count; i++) {
                    var room = this.rooms[i];
                    for (var x = room.x; x < room.x + room.w; x++) {
                        for (var y = room.y; y < room.y + room.h; y++) {
                            this.map[x][y] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (var x = 0; x < this.map_size; x++) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < this.map_size; y++) {
                        if (this.map[x][y] == 1) {
                            for (var xx = x - 1; xx <= x + 1; xx++) {
                                for (var yy = y - 1; yy <= y + 1; yy++) {
                                    if (this.map[xx][yy] == 0) this.map[xx][yy] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            FindClosestRoom: function (room) {
                var mid = {
                    x: room.x + (room.w / 2),
                    y: room.y + (room.h / 2)
                };
                var closest = null;
                var closest_distance = 1000;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.rooms.length; i++) {
                    var check = this.rooms[i];
                    if (check == room) continue;
                    var check_mid = {
                        x: check.x + (check.w / 2),
                        y: check.y + (check.h / 2)
                    };
                    var distance = Math.min(Math.abs(mid.x - check_mid.x) - (room.w / 2) - (check.w / 2), Math.abs(mid.y - check_mid.y) - (room.h / 2) - (check.h / 2));
                    if (distance < closest_distance) {
                        closest_distance = distance;
                        closest = check;
                    }
                }
                return closest;
            },
            SquashRooms: function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < this.rooms.length; j++) {
                        var room = this.rooms[j];
                        while (true) {
                            var old_position = {
                                x: room.x,
                                y: room.y
                            };
                            if (room.x > 1) room.x--;
                            if (room.y > 1) room.y--;
                            if ((room.x == 1) && (room.y == 1)) break;
                            if (this.DoesCollide(room, j)) {
                                room.x = old_position.x;
                                room.y = old_position.y;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            DoesCollide: function (room, ignore) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.rooms.length; i++) {
                    if (i == ignore) continue;
                    var check = this.rooms[i];
                    if (!((room.x + room.w < check.x) || (room.x > check.x + check.w) || (room.y + room.h < check.y) || (room.y > check.y + check.h))) return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        var Renderer = {
            canvas: null,
            ctx: null,
            size: 512,
            scale: 0,
            Initialize: function () {
                this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                this.canvas.width = this.size;
                this.canvas.height = this.size;
                this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                this.scale = this.canvas.width / Dungeon.map_size;
            },
            Update: function () {
                for (var y = 0; y < Dungeon.map_size; y++) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < Dungeon.map_size; x++) {
                        var tile = Dungeon.map[x][y];
                        if (tile == 0) this.ctx.fillStyle = '#351330';
                        else if (tile == 1) this.ctx.fillStyle = '#64908A';
                        else this.ctx.fillStyle = '#424254';
                        this.ctx.fillRect(x * this.scale, y * this.scale, this.scale, this.scale);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var Helpers = {
            GetRandom: function (low, high) {
                return~~ (Math.random() * (high - low)) + low;
            }
        };

        Dungeon.Generate();
        Renderer.Initialize();
        Renderer.Update(Dungeon.map);
        }
    </script>
</piece>
```

Comment: Java !=Javascript.

Comment: ??? what? what are you stating?

Comment: @Cleardragonf: It means that you should change "java" tag in your question into "javascript" tag because your question is related to JavaScript, not Java. And JavaScript experts can not see your question because you used wrong tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve